# How to mock RNEncryptedStorage with testing-library/react-native with Jest React Native

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am using testing-library/react-native for testing but problem is

```
RNEncryptedStorage is undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-encrypted-storage/lib/commonjs/EncryptedStorage.ts:7:9)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-encrypted-storage/lib/commonjs/index.ts:1:1)
```

Code :-

```
test('Videos should render OK', async () => {
  const {getByText, getByTestId, getAllByTestId, queryByText} = render(
    <Videos />,
  );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67915229/rnencryptedstorage-is-undefined-while-running-testing-library-react-native-with)

```js
__mocks__/react-native-encrypted-storage/index.js


const RNEncryptedStorage = {
  setItem: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
  getItem: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('{ "foo": 1 }')),
  removeItem: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
  clear: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
};

export default RNEncryptedStorage;
```